# Laravel: validating a form request using "where not in" database table

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

My current dilemma is this:

I have a form that I submit that indicates which rows I would like to delete from a database table.  We'll call this table1.

However, this row should not be allowed to be deleted if the row's id is located in another table (there is a foreign key constraint).  We'll call this table2.

Or, in other words, delete from table1 if the row's id isn't being referenced in table2.

In PHP, this would be simple for me to figure out.  And honestly, I could just hard code it in PHP inside of the controller but I want to use Laravel's validation errors because currently all of the other functionality uses said error handling.  The php equivalent I want to check is like this:

```
foreach($result->id as $id){
    if (DB::table('table2')->where('fk_column', $id)->count() == 0){
        DB::table('table1')->where('id', $id)->delete();
    }
}
```

I'm not seeing my problem answered anywhere that has a sufficient explanation of how the code works.  Is there a way to create a validation rule that does specifically this and spits out an error?  Is there a way to just run the PHP code and throw an error that can be put into the errors array?

Comment: I don't think there is something out of the box, you may need to write a custom validation rule. https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/validation It would be sort of the opposite of the `exists` rule.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest solution would be to make a custom validator.

In Laravel 5.4 you could probably also get the same effect by using `exists` validation rule with a custom query, as explained in the last example here https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/validation#rule-exists

That example is using `Rule::exists('staff')->where(function ($query) ...`, but API documentation lists that there's also whereNot() method available https://laravel.com/api/5.4/Illuminate/Validation/Rules/Exists.html#method_whereNot

So, I guess (be warned, I haven't tested it) you'd write it something like this:

```
Validator::make($data, [
    'delete_id' => [
        'required',
        Rule::exists('table2')->whereNot(function ($query) use ($data) {
            $query->where('fk_column', $data['delete_id']); 
        }),
        // ...
    ],
]);
```

Comment: "So, I guess (be warned, I haven't tested it)" --- then why did you post as "ANSWER" something you are not sure  100%??

Comment: To demonstrate the idea, so you could research further on it. Sorry for not giving you the copy&paste ready code, really inconsiderate of me...

Comment: Sorry mate, you have taken time to help someone, shoud be really appreciated. But as we "Answering" to the question, the answer should clear and it must resolve the question. In some cases, we can't be 100% sure and our answers can't be tested and user can further research,if the question is analytical / debatable... that's what i thought to say :)